# React router v6 routing issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spring-boot, react-router-dom

I am trying to create a spring boot application with react code inside it.I have my App.js like this.Only the default route is working and other routes are not working.

```
import './App.css';
import React from 'react';

import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css';
import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-balham.css';
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";
import 'react-js-dialog-box/dist/index.css';
import {BrowserRouter, BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes} from 'react-router-dom';
import UploadData from './UploadData';
import RoutesOfApplication from './RoutesOfApplication';
import '@szhsin/react-menu/dist/index.css';
import '@szhsin/react-menu/dist/transitions/slide.css';
//const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");

class App extends React.Component {
    render(){
    console.log('In App');
        return(
            
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
      
        <Route path="/" element={<RoutesOfApplication/>} />
        <Route path="/*" element={<RoutesOfApplication/>} />
        <Route path="/UploadData" element={<UploadData/>}/>
        <Route path="/:id" element={<UploadData/>}/>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
        );
    }   

}
export default App;


package.json : "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0"
```

Am i missing something.

Comment: Your path containing * wildcard should be the last `Route` component

Comment: @KasRoudra i tried that,but no luck.

Comment: By default route to you mean the root `"/"` path? Is this app deployed out on a server? Has the server/app been configured to redirect page requests to the sub-routes to the root index.html so the app loads and `react-router-dom` can handle rendering the correct page? See if any of the [CRA deployment docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/) are helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the `path = "/*"` on the 2nd path line may be causing the issue. If React went in order of routing, then that "/*" would be catching all of the routes and not processing /UploadData.

If this doesn't work, I noticed that you imported BrowserRouter twice from "react-router-dom", maybe delete the second time you imported it as an alias "BrowserRouter as Router"?

Hope this works!

if you changed the ordering or removed that path, does it work?

Comment: no luck with these changes as well.

Comment: sorry that wont be possible.

Comment: Alright no problem! I hope you can get this fixed!

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is you have a wildcard path `"/*"` and a dynamic path `"/:id"` in the same route.

The `"/:id"` route is a dynamic route, so react router doesn't care if its an a actual 32 bit unique id, or the word "hello". Therefore, it is a wildcard route (`"/*"`) as well, but with the added functionality of providing you with a parameter called `id` when using the `useParams` hook.

In your example, since all the routes are at the same level, the wildcard route will always win due to higher specificity (since it matches itself, the root path `"/"`,`/UploadData` and `"/:id"`). `"/UploadData"` can only match itself, `"/:id"`, and `/*` so it will always have lower specificity.

To remedy this, you can use relative routing by nesting routes inside routes, and use an index route to match whenever the children don't, instead of a wildcard. Below is an example.

```
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/">
           <Route path="UploadData" element={<UploadData/>}/>
           <Route path=":id" element={<UploadData/>}/>
           <Route index element = {<RoutesOfApplication/>} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

This way, on `"/"`, `"/UploadData"`, and `"/:id"` the right route is applied, and on any routes that don't match, the index is applied. Therefore, our routes are covered with the appropriate logic.

You can read more [here](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview#configuring-routes) on how react router version 6 chooses the right route **(based on SPECIFICTY)** and how to structure them

Answer (score 0):

Let's understand the components that are rendered with different paths.

```
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<h1/>Root Route</h1>} />
        <Route path="/*" element={<h1>Catch All Route</h1>} />
        <Route path="/UploadData" element={<h1>Upload Data Route</h1>} />
        <Route path="/:id" element={<h1>Id Route</h1>} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

With your current setup (as shown above) this is what happens:

- `/` renders `<h1/>Root Route</h1>`, which is desired.
- `/UploadData` renders `<h1>Upload Data Route</h1>`, which is also desired.
  **Note**: `/UploadData` also matches with `/:id` and `/*` paths but because path `/UploadData` is the more specific to
  others React Router resolves to `/UploadData`.
- `/1234` renders `<h1>Id Route</h1>` because it's more specific compared to `/*`.
- `/foo/bar` renders `<h1>Catch All Route</h1>`.

**NOTE**: Order of routes is not important with React Router V6, it's the specificity of the matching paths.

I guess the expectation is that `/foo` should resolve to the `path="/*"` route but in reality it resolves to `/:id` route because React Router doesn't know what your IDs are.

If you want `/foo` to show the catchall component you can test the validity of the `id` inside the component for the `id` route and if the id is not valid you can render the catchall component.

Refer the code snippet below:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, useParams } from "react-router-dom";

const CatchAllComponent = () => <h1>Catch All Route</h1>;
const IdComponent = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const isIdValid = /[0-9]/.test(id);

  if (isIdValid) {
    return <h1>Id Route</h1>;
  } else {
    return <CatchAllComponent />;
  }
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<h1>Root Route</h1>} />
        <Route path="/UploadData" element={<h1>Upload Data Route</h1>} />
        <Route path="/:id" element={<IdComponent />} />
        <Route path="*" element={<CatchAllComponent />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Comment: @PragatiPathak Does this solve your problem? Let me know if you have any queries!